# I'm using OpenCv to detect and draw a box around my left eye, and I want to find the center coordinate of that box, and place a dot on it

Tags: python, opencv

Here is a excerpt of code that draws the box around my eye, and contains my attempt to find and place a dot on the center coordinate, but for some reason it places the dot in the same place every time. I'm out of ideas and any help would be greatly appreciated! (ps: I can supply all of my code if needed)

```
    for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
        x_c = ex + (ex + ew - ex)/2
        y_c = ey + (ey + eh - ey)/2
        cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(img, (int(x_c), int(y_c)), (int(x_c), int(y_c)), (0, 0, 0), 5)
```

Comment: Try adding some print statements to show `ex`, `ey`, `ew`, `eh` and the results of your calculations so you can check if `x_c` and `y_c` are sensible. BTW `(ex+ew-ex)` can be simplified to `ew`.

Comment: After further inspection I found something odd. If I add a line to print ew it alternates between printing 1 int and 2 floats every line.

Comment: _I can supply all of my code if needed_. Please provide as much code as needed to reproduce the error, cf. the help site on [mre].